# For what values of $a$ the equation $(ax)^2-x^4=e^{|x|}$ have no solution

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find for what values of $a$ this equation have no solution.
the condition is $|a|<\sqrt{2}$
and the equation: $$(ax)^2-x^4=e^{|x|}$$
what I did so far is set ln on this equation:
$$2ln(ax)-4ln(x)=|x|$$

I would like to get some advice.
Thanks

Comment: The $\ln$ operation is not correct because it is applied for division or multiplication.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by $|a| < \sqrt{2}$?. Do we have to prove that when $|a|<\sqrt{2}$, the equation has no solution?

Comment: WA [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+%28x%5E4%2Be%5E%7Cx%7C%29%2Fx%5E2) that $a^2 < 3.69098$, and so $|a|<1.9212$. It is unlikely that there is a closed formula for this upper bound.

Comment: @lhf: and to use the method in your now deleted comment, that value of $a^2$ satisfies $$a^2 = \frac{4-y}{2-y} y^2$$ where $y$ solves $$ \ln 2 + 4 \ln y - \ln (2-y) = y $$ `:-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to consider nonnegative $x$, so the equation reads
$$ a^2x^2-x^4=e^x,\qquad x\ge0.$$
The left hand side is $=\frac14a^4-(x^2-\frac12a^2)^2\le\frac14a^4$, the right hand side $\ge e^0=1$, hence if $|a|<\sqrt 2$, we are done.

Comment: Ah, the $\sqrt{2}$ condition is not supposed to be sharp! That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: The actual supremum for $a$ is $\approx 1.9211930291664$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the interesting thing that I found

$1 \leqq e^{|x|} = x^2(a^2-x^2) \leqq \left(\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^2$

This implies that $a^2  \geqq 2$ or $|a| \geqq \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your function (the reversed [mexican hat potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_potential#A_pedagogical_example%3a_the_Mexican_hat_potential)) is symmetric just as $\text e^{|x|}$, so we just look at positive $x$. We have $\varphi(0)=0<\text e^0$ and so to show there is no intersection, it's sufficient to see that if $a<\sqrt{2}$ the rate of change of the function never excedes that of the exponential:

$$\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(a^2x^2-x^4)=2a^2x-4x^3< 4x-4x^3\le 1+x\le\text e^x=\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \text e^x,$$

Hence, the graph of $a^2x^2-x^4$ strictly stays below that of $\text e^x$.